# What is the best way to visualize a self-similarity matrix

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I have a string array that holds over 150 elements. I am trying to visualize a self-occurance matrix in a manner similar to [this](https://colinmorris.github.io/SongSim/#/). However, when I try to run the code, the load time is incredibly long.

I am using d3.js to visualize, and it's during the rendering process that most of the delay exists.

The matrix variable that I use in is an array of Link objects that have an x, y, id, weight property.

```js
let words: string[] = data.lyrics.replace(/[.,\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()]/g, "").replace(/\s{2,}/g, " ").split(" ");
let words_map: Map < string, number > = new Map();

let matrix: Array < Link > = new Array();
for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {
        let link: Link = {
            id: "(" + words[i] + " " + i.toString() + ", " + words[j] + " " + j.toString() + ")",
            x: i.toString(),
            y: j.toString(),
            weight: "0"
        }
        if (words[i].toUpperCase() === words[j].toUpperCase()) {
            if (words_map.has(words[i])) {
                words_map.set(words[i], words_map.get(lyrics[i]) + 1);
            } else {
                words_map.set(lyrics[i], 2)
            }
            link.weight = words_map.get(lyrics[i]).toString();
        }
        matrix.push(link);
    }
}

d3.select("svg")
    .append("g")
    .attr("id", "adjacencyG")
    .selectAll("rect")
    .data(matrix)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("width", 3)
    .attr("height", 3)
    .attr("x", function(d) {
        return parseInt(d.x) * 3
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
        return parseInt(d.y) * 3
    })
    .style("stroke", "black")
    .style("stroke-width", "1px")
    .style("fill", "red")
    .style("fill-opacity", function(d) {
        return parseInt(d.weight) * .2
    })
```

The runtime from the code above as I've pasted for an input array of 220 items takes 8 seconds to graph. With the code given is there any thing I can do to speed the rendering process up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try filtering some of the results out. If only some of the squares need to be filled, don't bother filling the other ones with white.

Comment: This solution worked before the d3 code is executed I ran: `const result = matrix.filter((element) => { element.weight >2 })` and the runtime was cut down significantly.